# Spark Sessions and Managed Tables using Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing a notebook with a conglomerate of info about PySpark, and the main idea is that one can run it multiple times while following a "course". The problem I'm running into is that if I create a table in a database for the first time, it all runs smoothly. Whereas, if I close the notebook and open it again -all data remains on the spark-warehouse folder- my queries can not find previously created tables.

Here is my code:

```
#Creating DataFrame
schema2 = "Product STRING, Quantity INT"
data4 = [('Pen', 9),('Pineappple', 22),('Apple', 12),('Pen', 13)]

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data4, schema2)

#####################################################################################
#Creating Database
spark.sql("show databases").show()

#Since the code could be executed multiple times in the same directory, this part raises a flag if the database already exists
try:
    spark.sql("create database ppap")
except pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:
    print('Unexpected Analysis Exception. Database may already exist')   

spark.sql("show databases").show() #Checking if everything worked out well... ~(˘-˘~)

spark.sql("use ppap") #Selecting Database

#####################################################################################
#Creating Table from DataFrame
try:
    df2.write.saveAsTable("ppap")
    print('New table added to current database.')
except pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException:
    print('Unexpected Analysis Exception. Table may already exist') 

#####################################################################################
#Running queries
spark.sql("select * from ppap").show()

spark.sql("show tables").show()
```

Here is the output when I run the first time:

```
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
+---------+

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|     ppap|
+---------+

A new table was added to the current database.
+----------+--------+
|   Product|Quantity|
+----------+--------+
|       Pen|       9|
|Pineappple|      22|
|     Apple|      12|
|       Pen|      13|
+----------+--------+

+---------+---------+-----------+
|namespace|tableName|isTemporary|
+---------+---------+-----------+
|     ppap|     ppap|      false|
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

The tables are not temporary, so I figured they would remain after the end of the SparkSession. Now, here is what I get when I close and reopen the same notebook:

```
+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
+---------+

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|     ppap|
+---------+

Unexpected Analysis Exception. The table may already exist.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [25], in <module>
     27     print('Unexpected Analysis Exception. Table may already exist') 
     29 #####################################################################################
     30 #Running queries
---> 31 spark.sql("select * from ppap").show()
     33 spark.sql("show tables").show()
.
.
.

AnalysisException: Table or view not found: ppap; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [ppap], [], false
```

Furthermore, I can only get the first output if I delete the folder spark-warehouse and rerun the block which creates this table.